# simple interest rate to product of interest rates

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

> Which simple interest rate over six years is closest to being equivalent to the following: an effective rate of discount of 3% for the first year, an effective rate of discount of 6% for the second year, an effective rate of discount of 9% for the third year, and an effective rate of interest of 5% for the fourth, fifth and sixth years?
>
> A. 6.3%    B. 6.4% C. 6.5% D. 6.6% E. 6.7%

So I thought we were supposed to apply this formula:

$FV=PV(1+i)^t = PV \cdot v^{-t}=PV(1-d)^{-t}$

d = rate of discount

i=effective rate of interest

v= present value factor

So my approach was this:

$(1-0.03)^{-1}(1-0.06)^{-2}(1-0.09)^{-3}(1.05)^4(1.05)^5(1.05)^6=(1+6i)$

solving for i you get 37% which is obviously wrong.  Can someone please explain the proper approach?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so.  5% is effective interest rate, NOT discount rate.  I think the answer is $(1-.03)^{-1} (1-0.06)^{-1} (1-0.09)^{-1} (1.05)^3 = 1+6i \implies i=6.6\%$

Comment: Yes, this is how you would do it.  Since you answered your own question, please write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effective rate of (simple) interest would be: $(1 - 0.03)^{-1}(1 - 0.06)^{-1}(1 - 0.09)^{-1}(1 + 0.05)^3 = (1 + 6i) \implies i \approx 6.6\%$